# SET THE RIGHT DOMAIN NAME IN MAGENTO 2 COOKIES

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend, cookie

I set cookies (in Magento 2.3.1 EE) with this code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/jquery.cookie'
], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var check_cookie_store_source = $.cookie('StoreSource');
        var check_cookie_store_locator_store_id = $.cookie('store_locator_store_id');
        console.log('set Just In');
        if (!check_cookie_store_source){
            $.cookie('StoreSource', '5');
            console.log('set check_cookie_store_source');
        }
        if (!check_cookie_store_locator_store_id){
            $.cookie('store_locator_store_id', '10');
            console.log('set check_cookie_store_locator_store_id');
        }
    });
});
```

So Now, I need to have magento2.docker in domain name not **.magento2.docker** (*check dot before*).

I also use this sentaxe :

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/', domain: 'magento2.docker' });
```

I continue to get **dot(.)** before my domain name, please help me understand and solve this probleme
[image: My Console Cookies log in my brower]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Cookie domains with a prefix . are set by the server when your browser receives a response, and cookies created with javascript are without the prefix.

You do not need the dot (.) before the domain, and subdomains will work under the parent domain.

Comment: Thank you for you answer